# Stacked bar chart from one column pandas or dictionary

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked

I have been trying to create a stacked bar chart from simple data.

Assume the dictionary:

```
data ={A:2,B:3, C:4, D:5}
```

I would like to create a bar chart that shows like this:

[image: example]

I cant do it manually (i.e. dividing A by the total and so on) since I have a dictionary that consists of 20 keys.

I feel like it should be so simple but I can't figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pd.Series(data).to_frame().T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]